# jquery multiple classes detect classes partially and fetch each class individually

Tags: jquery, html, regex, class, each

I am trying to achieve bellow:

```
<input type="text" name="some_name" id="some_id" class="prefix_type_tags prefix_separator_comma etc etc" />
```

I have multiple elements of this kind on my page (generated dynamically), so I want to detect

```
jQuery('[class^=prefix_]').each(function(){
    //solution????
});
```

and here I want to detect each class individually, like I want to detect if I have **type** partial class or **separator** partial class in their and if yes, then I want to get the last portion of the class like in `prefix_type_tags` case I want to get **tags**, and in `prefix_separator_comma` case I want to get **"comma"**, so any body have any solution?

I don't want it to be split, or similar solution, I would prefer to match with `regex`!

Comment: Why no split? Why do you want regex? Gurvinder's solution looks like it seems fine!

Comment: I want it to be more reliable, by splitting, I will have to be careful about classes length, or separators like "my_class" in this case "_", I don't want that, I would prefer class extraction using regex and then get its last part.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('[class^=prefix_]').each(function(){
    var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    for ( var counter = 0; counter < classList.length; counter ++ )
    {
         var classname = classList[ counter ];
         var lastPart = classname.split("_")[2];

         //you can now do whatever you want to do with lastPart
    }
});
```

Comment: This is close, but not exactly what I am looking for (I tried it and works fine), but doesn't fulfil my requirement. see my fiddle here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saas786/S9mDb/)
I need to first detect if I have the class (partially), like in above code I would like to see if my html element have first "select2_" prefix, then I will run a  loop on each, and then I will detect / search "type" in each element classes, so if I found any then I will further extract the lastPart like you did above. Following me????